# How i delete data cart in session after finish shpping ? (Angularjs)

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter, session

I have a program shopping cart build with Codeigniter in backend and angularjs for computation frontend. my problem is after finish shopping how I delete session cart so that data cart is empty.

I create a session cart with manually, not with codeigniter shopping cart library.

Comment: i create module cart with angular, not codeigniter\

Comment: perhaps add some code then so it isn't a guessing game. you mentioned a session, a session is server-side (not client-side i.e. angular).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the some points, which may be helpfull for you

1) If you have done the cart functionality using `codeigniter session` use 
`$this->session->unset_userdata('your_cart_variable_name');` or if your using session only for cart functionality you can destroy all the session data using `session_destroy();`.

2) If you are storing shopping cart products in database table, delete the perticular rows.

3) If you are using codeigniter `shopping cart class` use `$this->cart->destroy();`  to destroy shopping cart.